# Converting Clipping stage of guitar pedal to a formula for use in DSP

Tags: filter, dsp

Been trying to figure out the clipping stage of a tube screamer so i can implement it in a DSP project.

[image: Tube Screamer Clipping Circuit]

I can simulate a clipping effect by using a tanh(input) type function, which gives me an OK approximation, but the R4,C3 high pass filter in the feedback loop is what i'm having trouble with.

I've designed an IIR high pass filter with a ~700Hz cut off point, but i don't know how to properly "fit" it into the code. If i apply filter AFTER the tanh(input) function, it's the equivalent of removing C3 and adding it in series (with a 4.7k resistor to gnd) at OUT pin.

If i apply it before tanh function, it's the equivalent of adding a high pass filter to IN signal, then Clipping..

Regardless i can't get that phase effect from the feedback that i see when simulating this circuit. 
(NB: Simplified with no low pass feedback cap, etc)

[image: High Pass phase effect on OUT pin]

Comment: That whole circuit is meant to emulate a tube, while that `tanh()` is also meant to emulate the tube, but without the need for such complicated transfer functions. Also see [this on DSP.EE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36202/17189) for less comutationally intensive functions, soft-clipping functions.

Comment: I can emulate the clipping no problem, but i wan't to emulate the effect of the high pass filter that gives the output it's distinct phase characteristics! From looking at the waveform it seems to me like a a filtered version of the input (at low frequencies this should introduce a phase shift) is added to the clipped signal..